# In postgresql character varying data type can consider a dot as a char?

Tags: postgresql

in PostgreSQL, we can insert a data like "." with size>10 when the data type is character varying (10).
Is dot considered as a string in PostgreSQL?
i did not find information in the documentation.

Comment: Are you asking if the dot is a valid character?

Comment: A '.' is a "normal" valid character; and `'Huh..?'` is a valid SQL string literal. If punctuation was not allowed then English prose could not be stored directly in the database, which would make many koi sad.

Comment: no you can't. the size limit on character varying(10) is 10 characters.  this doesn't limit you to 10 octets, but does limit you to 10 characters.

Comment: This is trivial to test. What did you see when you tested it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having some trouble understanding the question, so I'll answer it how I understood it.

I just tested it, and setting `"."` as the value of a column's working for me (PostgreSQL 9.5; I'm using Postico). As long as there's no constraints (like uniqueness, must be a UUID, ...), it seems that the period is treated like any other character.

**EDIT:** If Postgres has a limit of 10, you can't store a string like `".........."`, which is more than length 10 (just tested on SQLFiddle).

Comment: so if the dot is considered like a character with postgresql is allowing an entry with more than 10 dot when the size is limitied to 10? In this case user2864740 is wrong, for Balin, yes for me too it works but my question about the size of the data type. thank you

Comment: no i do not understand your edit, why PostgreSQL accepts more than 10 chars when it is limited to 10?

Comment: Hi Balin everything is ok now, i was testing from my home and the env was not stable, thank you for your help